# Is it possible to run Apache Flume as daemon service?

Tags: apache, hadoop, cloudera, flume

I would like to ask- how can I run Apache Flume as a Linux daemon service?
I know that Cloudera in CDH and Hortonworks in HDH are doing it with their third party distribution Hadoops. 
But how can I do it with ordinary Hadoop and Flume from Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the flume agent using nohup such as:-

```
nohup bin/flume-ng agent -n agent_name -c conf -f conf/flume-conf.properties.template &
```

Comment: it is one choice but this is a pseudo-service, you can just kill it, you cant say
service something start/stop

Comment: You can start stop agent using the following commands:-
bin/flume-ng agent start & 
bin/flume-ng agent stop

Comment: Yuvraj, thanks a lot. However as I see in ADH,  bin/flume-ng agent start  is still running agent as a session based process.
nohup is much more good but it is still not a Linux server which is accessible via "service" command...

Comment: I am not sure but you can run the agent command using nohup. Maybe it will serve your purpose :)